# disable custom marker click event

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have tried [How to disable marker click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197027/how-to-disable-marker-click-event),[How do I disable click on a map marker in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722649/how-do-i-disable-click-on-a-map-marker-in-android) and [How to disable android map marker click auto center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925319/how-to-disable-android-map-marker-click-auto-center) link but still marker is tapable and it remove the displayed info-window.please suggest me a right solution.

**CODE**

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 12.0f));
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindow());
        marker.showInfoWindow();/*Show infowindow by default.*/
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(null);/*Disable click on info wndow.*/
        mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);/*Disable map scrolling.*/
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you getting any stack trace.

Comment: no i am not getting any kind of information in stack trace

Comment: above links working for others and got well votes. Do check with those again.

Comment: sir i have already mention that code above and it is not working in my case thats why i opened a new question so that i can find a right solution